# search value in multi array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays (array_1 and array_2).
This is the structure:

**array_1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => Array
                (
                    [0] => mail@domain.de
                )

            [ID] => 489
        )

)
```

**array_2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => Array
                (
                    [0] => test@domain.de
                )

            [ID] => 13
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => Array
                (
                    [0] => mail@domain.de
                    [1] => yourmail@domain.de
                )

            [ID] => 48
        )

)
```

Now I would like to check, if the mail address "mail@domain.de" (`array_1[0]['email'][0]`) exist in array_2. And If yes: I need to know the key of array_2, where the mail address was found.

I tried `array_search()` but this seems not work with multi arrays.
Can you help me please? Thanks !!

**array_1 var_export()**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'email' => 
    array (
      0 => 'mail@domain.de',
    ),
    'customerID' => '489',
  ),
)
```

**array_2 var_export()**

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'email' => 
    array (
      0 => 'test@domain.de',
    ),
    'customerID' => '13',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'email' => 
    array (
      0 => 'mail@domain.de',
      1 => 'yourmail@domain.de',
    ),
    'customerID' => '48',
  ),
)
```

Comment: So, the answer for this is `0` or `48`?

Comment: the result should be `array_2[1]` because this is the key in array_2, where the mail was found

Comment: Ok, so result should be `1`.

Comment: yes , it should be `1`

Comment: I updated my first post

Comment: "I tried array_search() but this seems not work with multi arrays." It certainly does. Why not share your attempts?

Comment: I tried `array_search(array_1[0]['email'],$array_2)` but the result will be empty

Comment: @miken32 It doesn't due to the search needing to be recursive in nature. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/713098a6bdd3c3f85e8f3da7279076adb614f106

Comment: Sure but you can run it in a recursive function no problem.

Comment: @miken32 `array_walk_recursive` sounds promising but it only visits leaf nodes directly. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php#112339

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `array_filter` combined with `array_search`. If an array is found, it automatically casts to a boolean (true/false) thus returning the parent array.

Update: `array_search` returns the index of value: if the index is `0`, it is casted as false so a strict-type check for `false` should be made which fixes any bugs.

[See it working over at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/51QE7)

```
array_filter($array, fn($x) => array_search('yourmail@domain.de', $x['email']) !== false);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => Array
                (
                    [0] => mail@domain.de
                    [1] => yourmail@domain.de
                )

            [customerID] => 48
        )

)
```

Update: If `array_search` is throwing unexpected results, try using `in_array` instead perhaps.

```
array_filter($array, fn($x) => in_array('yourmail@domain.de', $x['email']));
```

Update: Any empty results, without context, I assume it isn't an array and in-fact is a string so you could append the checks to the function:

```
&& is_array($x['email']) && !empty($x['email'])
```

Comment: this looks good ! I like it ! but there is a "bug"? I get the correct result but I get also a  second result, where the ['email'] is empty.

Comment: Provide a full, minimalistic example of your data and I will fix it. Your provided example has no empty values. @Ghost108

Comment: An assumption, without any context to what you mean by empty, try adding `&& is_array($x['email']) && !empty($x['email'])`, or similar. @Ghost108

Comment: yes this works !!! perfect ! thank you very much !! :)

Comment: No worries. You could potentially just use `in_array` and subsidise the `array_search` here. Glad to help. @Ghost108

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `array_walk_recursive` 
A crude example:

```
$email = 'mail@domain.de'

function checkEmail($item, $key)
{
    if ($item === $email) {
       echo $key;
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($array2, 'checkEmail');
```

More in docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: What is the value of `$email` inside function `checkEmail()`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need the subarray index of where it was found, you could

- Loop on each subarray and call a search function, say `checkValueExistence` which returns `true` or `false` depending on the search result. If the func returns `true`, return the index, else `-1` or `false` indicating the value(in your case email) was not found.
- `checkValueExistence` will simply loop through the array at hand and check if any value matches the supplied one and if the current iteration value in context is an array in itself, it recursively calls itself for this new subarray.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php
    
function getValueIndex($data, $val){
    foreach($data as $idx => $d){
        if(checkValueExistence($d, $val) === true){
            return $idx;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
    // you could also throw an exception via throw new \Exception("$val is not found in the dataset"); and a try-catch block in the callee code 
}

function checkValueExistence($data, $val){
    foreach($data as $value){
        if(is_array($value) && checkValueExistence($value, $val) || !is_array($value) && $value === $val) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

echo getValueIndex($data, 'mail@domain.de');
```

[**Online Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9c19537cf357f29c9246b82676e9f802f98efb2)

Comment: thanks for your support. but your example has got only one array. My example shows 2 arrays. is this a problem?

Comment: @Ghost108 Not really.. I just manually supplied the email here `echo getValueIndex($data, 'mail@domain.de');`

Comment: ah I see ! And I tried it with my situation and it works! Thanks ! But there is no "easier" way to do this??

Comment: @Ghost108 I am afraid a much easier way is less likely to exist. I will ping you if I find one

Comment: Not exactly understand where [your `-1`](https://3v4l.org/6S7AL) best practice is coming from. Just return `false`.

Comment: @Jaquarh Updated. My first intuition was to return -1 indicating the index was not found as the OP wanted. Yes, returning false as I had initially mentioned in the code comments is also a good approach or maybe even throwing an exception